# Why am I rep capped today with only 190 rep?

Tags: support, reputation

As per how I believed the site worked, you must achieve 200 rep minimum a day to be rep capped.

However, my user info panel states today...

[image: My user info panel]

Has something changed?

#### Update

Just then, my rep jumped to 192 for today, though someone may have removed a downvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that you reached the rep cap of 200 and then weren't able to receive anymore reputation etc (your 0 score for example)

However, if you had previously received an upvote (of 10 points) for an Answer that was removed (not downvoted, but removed) then it would take away from your 200 (e.g. 200 back to 190). If you have multiple answers on various votes and one of them lost an upvote it would be hard to tell that in fact it had gone backwards.

Regardless, you can always go to the [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) to have it recalculated.

Answer (score 5):

When viewing your account right now, [it's showing 200](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31671/alex?tab=reputation)?

Comment: It is there, but not in my info panel. Weird.

Comment: Very wierd.  Perhaps one of the devs could take a look at this from the backend.